# netbeans runs program even if there are errors in code

Tags: java, netbeans, compiler-construction

so, I accidentally chose "don't show me this message again" and "Run anyways".  is there a way to undo this setting?  Like there can be typos throughout the program, and it'll still try to run.  I don't want this, because if there's a section of code that might not be called while i'm testing the program, I might not notice the error.

newest version, 7.4 NetBeans EE for windows

if a function call is actually made to the "uncompilable source code", then it gives such an error

I can search through the program manually line by line, making sure there are no red squiggly lines, but this seems impractical.  perhaps I should just re-install netbeans?

Comment: Which version of NetBeans and OS do you have?

Comment: newest version, 7.4 NetBeans EE for windows

Comment: Tell me one thing after run program, what error message do you get?

Comment: well, if a function call is actually made to the "uncompilable source code", then it gives such an error

Comment: if someone like me came here to find just the opposite: how to get that popup shown, I've found it, activate `Compile on save` in project settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to multiple posts on the Internet, you should remove the `BuildArtifactMapperImpl.properties` file in the `<netbeans home>/<version>/config/Preferences/org/netbeans/modules/java/source/` directory (where it is depends on your installation). 
It should have the `askBeforeRunWithErrors` property set to false. Some just fixed buy deleting the whole file.

Personally, I do not have that file but I have not checked that option, so it might be generated at that point.

Comment: using windows 8.1, I found that hidden folder in the User/Appdata/Roaming/Netbeans/7.4/config/Preferences/org/netbeans/modules/java/source/ directory

Answer (score 0):

how about you delete the settings file stored in the your user DIR as an xml file. it will reset netbeans bac to defaults. or you can edit it and locate parameter  askBeforeRunWithErrors to false as it's set to true.

Answer (score -2):

There is a red *stop* button in the `output` window. Click that.

[image]

There is a [bug](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=186776) in NB forum. And another forum [reply](http://forums.netbeans.org/ntopic43355.html) says that

> Don't bother - found it after making a directory diff :
>
> Simply remove the file
>
> .netbeans/7.0/config/Preferences/org/netbeans/modules/java/source/BuildArtifactMapperImpl.properties

Comment: wrong error.  if like void functionX() {  Systensfd..ouits.pringt();}  is in a class but not called, the program will still run.  I don't want this to happen

Comment: Yes that's what I said click the *stop* button.

Comment: That's not what the OP asked. He wants NB to terminate the launch on such an error, not to run it at all.

Comment: @Downvoters can you explain why I get downvotes where same type of answer get accepted? Just because I'm slow in googling?

Comment: You already got your explanation. You are explaining to the main how to stop an application that has semantic errors and is executed. The user knows how to stop the application, but he wants to re-enable the option in the IDE to automatically deny (or at least ask what to do) when the application has this kind of serious error.
That is a very useful check because programmers make all kinds of mistakes and in a large code base almost every aid is very valuable.
You added wanted answer later, when you saw your mishap. You would be better deleting the original and writing a new one.